# Will my google analytics still work if I put it in a linked javascript file?

Tags: analytics

I just want an easier, cleaner code for my Web pages. So I thought I could link to the javascript of the google code from a script call. Will it still log the page just the same? Thank you.

Comment: It'll be slower and potentially break if Google updates their end.

Comment: Not sure, but you could use this debugging tool for chrome to check: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: You will end up making an extra HTTP request, and depending on the timing of it, you may miss some users if they bounce from your page very fast. But will likely "work" in most instances.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do so and it mostly worked.

The biggest problem with it as far as I could tell is that Analytics couldn't validate that the snippet was installed by crawling my site.  I went back to embedding it directly.

Comment: Thank you. As a result, I'm going back to embedding it as you did.